# how to autogenerate array in kotlin similar to numpy?

Tags: kotlin

hello let me do a demonstration in python about what I want to achieve in kotlin:

```py
np.linspace(start = 0, stop = 100, num = 5)
```

This results:

```
-------------------------
|0 | 25 | 50 | 75 | 100 |
-------------------------
```

Now in Kotlin how can I get the same result? Is there a similar library?

Answer (score 5):

This should work exactly like linspace (not handling cases when num is 0 or 1):

```
fun linspace(start: Int, stop: Int, num: Int) = (start..stop step (stop - start) / (num - 1)).toList()
```

It makes use of the range`start..stop` (a range in kotlin is inclusive) and the function `step` lets us define how far the steps in this ranges should be.

**EDIT**
As @forpas suggested in the comments the step should be calculated using `(stop - start)` and not only `stop`. Using `stop` alone would only work if the `start` was `0`.

@Alexey Romanov correctly said that **unless you explicitly need a List** as return type you should return the `IntProgression` (it does not hold all the elements in memory like a list does) since its also `Iterable`.

Thank you both for your input!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, does this function accept decimals? for example from 0.5 to 34.6

Comment: Sadly this would only work with Integers. The `range` function would accept decimal as well but `step` does not.

Comment: @royer iterating over floating point numbers is generally a bad idea because they're vulnerable to rounding errors.

Comment: I'd suggest removing `toList` unless you need it specifically as a `List`. The return type of `step` will be `IntProgression`, which is iterable and enough for most purposes.

Comment: Shouldn't the step be: `(stop - start) / (num - 1)`?

Comment: And what I forgot to say is that `IntProgression` doesn't need to hold its elements in memory like `List` does.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly the same, but it generates an array with 5 integers, multiples of `25` starting from `0`:

```
val array = Array(5) { it * 25  }
```

the result is:

```
[0, 25, 50, 75, 100]
```

You can create a function simulating what you need:

```
fun linspace(start: Int, stop: Int, num: Int) = Array(num) { start + it * ((stop - start) / (num - 1)) }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, does this function accept decimals? for example from 0.5 to 34.6

Comment: Inside the lambda `it` is the index of the array and you can multiply it by any numeric data type. For example:  `{ it * 0.25  }` will produce `[0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]` an `Array<Double>`.

Answer (score 2):

`DoubleProgression` used to exist but [was removed](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/6bac3e1986c69fcba3cb4333a1f84d01cd281490), because it raises rounding issues; you can copy the sources from that commit as a starting point if you really need it. Or consider converting it to a `BigDecimalProgression` instead. Of course, you need division to get the step from your arguments, which isn't exact even for `BigDecimal`.

You can also use [sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/index.html):

```
fun linspaceD(start: Double, stop: Double, num: Double): Sequence<Double> {
    val step = (stop - start) / (num - 1)
    return sequence {
        for i in 0 until num yield(start + step*i)
    }
}
```

Note that this resolves rounding in a specific way, by always yielding `num` values even if the last one is slightly greater than `stop`.

Comment: Nice solution! and thanks for the insight about the DoubleProgression